# Problems with php date

Tags: php, date

I've run into a bit of trouble with the PHP date function (I have almost 0 knowledge when it comes to this).

I want to get the next 5 days of the week saved in 3 parameter like variables such as `$month`, `$dayofmonth` and `$dayofweek` and having it displayed June 4 Tuesday, each part of the date to be able to be put inside its coresponding html div elements.

I've experimented for the last 2 days with different codes but none worked and 3 hours ago I came to the conclusion that the way I was getting the month, I would have a conflict at the end of the month, because the name changes. So I would have had May 31 Friday, May 1 Saturday, May 2 Sunday etc.

What i have for now, i think i've corrected the problem with end of the month.

```
$month = date("F");
$day_1 = date("j");
$day_2 = date("j", strtotime("+1 days"));
$day_3 = date("j", strtotime("+2 days"));
$day_4 = date("j", strtotime("+3 days"));
$day_5 = date("j", strtotime("+4 days"));
$wday_1 = date("l");
$wday_2 = date("l", strtotime("+1 weekday"));
$wday_3 = date("l", strtotime("+1 weekday"));
$wday_4 = date("l", strtotime("+1 weekday"));
$wday_5 = date("l", strtotime("+1 weekday"));
$next_month = date("F", strtotime("+1 month"));
echo $day_1." ".$wday_1." ";
if($day_1 == 28 || $day_1 == 29 || $day_1 == 30 || $day_1 == 31 || $day_2 == 28 || $day_2 == 29 || $day_2 == 30 || $day_2 == 31 ||
$day_3 == 28 || $day_3 == 29 || $day_3 == 30 || $day_3 == 31 || $day_4 == 28 || $day_4 == 29 || $day_4 == 30 || $day_4 == 31 ||
$day_5 == 28 || $day_5 == 29 || $day_5 == 30 || $day_5 == 31) { $month = $next_month; }
echo $month;
```

I have read the documentation about date but i need every part of the date in a different variable that can be easily used in localisation changes and SQL selects.

Comment: You need to show us your code.  There's a VERY easy way to do what you're describing, if only you'd be more specific about what that is and what you've tried.

Comment: At this moment i have no more code, i've started again from scratch, i'll post when i get something done that tends to work somewhat how it should. ~20/30 minutes

Comment: Have you tried using `strtotime('+1 days');`, changing 1 to whatever amount you need?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Follows attached a simple program that prints all days of 2013 in the format that you want, with day, month and week separated by divs..

I advise you see [date format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to understand the many ways to print formmated date.

```
<?php

$inicio = new DateTime();
$inicio->setDate(2013, 1, 1);


$fim = new DateTime();
$fim->setDate(2014, 1, 1);

while($inicio < $fim)
{


    echo "<div>";
    echo $inicio->format("M"); 
    echo "</div>";

    echo "<div>";
    echo $inicio->format("j");
    echo "</div>";

    echo "<div>";
    echo $inicio->format("l");
    echo "</div>";

    echo "<br>";

    $inicio->add(new DateInterval('P1D')); // sums 1 day in date

}


?>
```

Comment: Thank you, with your code i decided to change the main code and turn it into a side scrolling type calendar with everything in it and i will make it advance to the current date with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this is use a [DatePeriod](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php); instances of DatePeriod are iterable so you can use them in foreach loops.

```
// a date period starting today spanning 5 days and separated into 1 day segments
$period = new \DatePeriod(new \DateTime(), new \DateInterval('P1D'), 4);
foreach ($period as $day) {
  echo $day->format('F j l');
}
```

This *may be* a bit of overkill for what you want to do but DatePeriods often get overlooked which is unfortunate because they can be really handy.

Answer (score 0):

Use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects instead of just the `date()` function. If I understand correctly what you want, you can just do this:

```
$date = new DateTime();
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; ++$i) {
    echo $date->format('F j l'); // Month, day of month, day of week
    $date->modify('+1 day'); // this will change the timestamp stored in
                             // the DateTime object accordingly.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation you should have read](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) before "experimenting for the last 2 days with different codes", you can simply get the dates you need without any variables whatsoever using something like this:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    date("F j l", strtotime("+".$i." days"));
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php